# Generate a pdf with dynamic datas from a database table row, on a button click

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to print a certificate(pdf) on a button click, in wordpress. I have to write name and course name into the pdf which is stored in a file. and then download it. Name and course name is fetched from db table row. Can u please help me. Thanks in advance

code given below:

```
<?php

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once( 'FPDF-master/fpdf.php' );
require_once( 'FPDI-master/src/autoload.php' );

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile('certificate.pdf');
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at position 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->SetXY(60, 60);
$pdf->Write(0, 'bk');

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are tons of PDF libraries you could use, like FPDF, Dompdf, TCPDF,... - grab one and have a try :) if you have a **specific** question about one of these tools, please share your code

Comment: Thanks for the response. FPDF standalone worked fine for me. But when comes to wordpress it doesn't. I had tried FPDF-FPDI. . When initiating $pdf = new Fpdi(); it doesn't work. Call to the fpdf class respond nothing. If i remove all codes in that fpdf and just print something, it displays that string i tried to print. Nothing works inside class

Comment: "Nothing works inside class" - then you should share some of that code in question. Are you sure that all includes are done properly, such that namespacing and autoloading works?

Comment: use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once( 'FPDF-master/fpdf.php' );
require_once( 'FPDI-master/src/autoload.php' );

$pdf = new Fpdi(); from here when the call goes to fpdf class, it doesnt work.

Comment: Please add that code to your question, not to the comment section. And I don't get how this code should not work - it does not produce any output, so getting a blank page is fine. Additionally, how is that related to "nothing works inside class"?

Comment: i am getting a blank page. So i tried to print something inside class of fpdf library. I got stucked

Answer (score 0):

Try DKPdf plugin. You can customise the PDF layout with the plugin file in child theme. It works nicely with custom post type as well.